# Does malloc only allocate memory, nothing else?

Tags: c, malloc

Code goes first:

```
struct yo
{
    char *name;
    int several[10];
    int num;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct yo *test_yo = malloc(sizeof(struct yo));
    printf("%p\t%p\t%p\n", (void *)&test_yo->name, (void *)&test_yo->num, (void *)&test_yo->several);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is: If malloc only allocates some memory space and return a pointer to it, how does test_yo find the address of its name, num and several - since test_yo is just a pointer to a bunch of garbage? Does malloc actually doing some extra work here like aligning struct members and recording the memory address of the members?

Comment: After the compiler has performed type-checking, a `struct` is nothing more than a collection of offsets. `malloc` has absolutely no idea about datatypes, or structs, or anything like that. You wan't `sizeof(struct yo)` bytes? Here you go, a new block of 18 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with malloc. What happens is very simple - referring to a structure member by pointer X simply adds an offset to a memory address stored in the pointer X (its value). Therefore, you simply apply offsets to a pointer returned by malloc.

Remember, structures do not exists in compiled binaries - it is merely a compile-time "concept" of high-level programming languages. You may even get the offset of each member of the structure using [`offsetof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof) macro.

Therefore, it doesn't really matter where you get the pointer and what its value is, you can always compute an address of a "field" of a structure by applying adding its offset (which is always known to compiler) to the value stored in pointer.

Here is a little example to demonstrate this:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct my_struct {
        int x;
        int y;
};

int main()
{
        struct my_struct *s;

        /* Print relative offsets of the structure member fields: */
        printf("Offset of 'x': %lu\n", offsetof(struct my_struct, x));
        printf("Offset of 'y': %lu\n", offsetof(struct my_struct, y));

        /*
         * Assign some random memory address to a pointer and print addresses
         * of the structure and its members. You can see that they are related,
         * pointer to 'x' will always be the same as pointer to structure +
         * `offsetof(struct my_struct, x)` and pointer to 'y' as pointer to
         * structure + `offsetof(struct my_struct, y)`
         */
        s = (void *)0xDEADBEEF;
        printf("Pointer to structure: %p\n", s);
        printf("Pointer to x: %p (x - base = %ld)\n",
               &s->x, (ptrdiff_t)&s->x - (ptrdiff_t)s);
        printf("Pointer to y: %p (y - base = %ld)\n",
               &s->y, (ptrdiff_t)&s->y - (ptrdiff_t)s);

        return 0;
}
```

Results can be different on different platforms, here are mine on Intel x86_64:

```
$ clang -Weverything -o test ./test.c && ./test
Offset of 'x': 0
Offset of 'y': 4
Pointer to structure: 0xdeadbeef
Pointer to x: 0xdeadbeef (x - base = 0)
Pointer to y: 0xdeadbef3 (y - base = 4)
```

Note that you can always compute and field offset in runtime. The main different from `offsetof` is that it can be used to compute offsets in [compile-time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_time).

Also, be careful when trying to calculate field offsets yourself. Though compiler cannot re-arrange fields, it can easily perform [padding and alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment), effectively adding implicit "empty" space in between field members, if needed.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: So what really happens is that test_yo gets the address first, and then compiler figures that test_yo is a pointer to struct yo, so then the compiler aligns different members inside the memory test_yo points to, is that right?

Comment: @Xufeng: Absolutely. `.` and `->` operators are just convenient C syntax. You could refer to members without those operators if you know their offsets (that's what people programming in assembly have to do).

Comment: @Xufeng: I'd correct phrasing a little tho - compiler does not align anything when you refer to field member through you pointer. It aligns structure when it sees a declaration for the first time - at that point it decides on offsets for each field. When you refer to a member through the pointer, it simply applies that offset it calculated before.

Comment: If so, when the compiler sees the struct the first time, it aligns the struct and defines all its members? That's why I can refer to its members even I only create a pointer to the whole struct?

Comment: @Xufeng: Yeap, you pretty much got it.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler works that out. i.e. `sizeof` works out the space required and the compiler works out how to arrange the various items in that memory

Answer (score 1):

The `malloc` function itself doesn't align the members of your structure, that's done by the compiler long before the program ever runs. For example, on a system with eight-byte pointers and four-byte integers, it's likely that:

- `name` will be at the start of the structure;
- `several` will be at offset 8; and
- `num` will be at offset 48 (to allow for `several` having ten four-byte elements).

All `malloc` does is give you some memory at least big enough to put that structure in (or gives you NULL if it can't find enough memory).

The locating of the fields *within* the structure is done by the code accessing said structure.

Answer (score 0):

malloc allocates the memory only. The C compiler knows at compile time that the structure 'yo' contains three fields including a field called 'name' which is at structure offset 0, etc.

The compiler therefore takes the pointer returned from malloc, adds the *known* structure field offset and you end up with the address you describe pointing directly to the members.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` just allocates a specific amount of memory.  It returns a generic pointer (i.e., `void*`).

The compiler sees the struct, and knows its layout.

If you have a different type, you will get different values (note the code below uses the exact same pointer to heap-allocated memory).

```
struct foo { int i, j, k };
struct bar { char i, j, k; };
void *ptr = malloc(100);
struct foo * fooptr = (struct foo *)ptr;
struct bar * barptr = (struct bar *)ptr;
printf("foo: %p, %p, %p\n", &fooptr->i, &fooptr->j, &fooptr->k);
printf("bar: %p, %p, %p\n", &barptr->i, &barptr->j, &barptr->k);
```

Answer (score 0):

A struct in C is a very ... um... structured block of memory.  Assuming a host system with 32-bit pointers and 32-bit integers, then`name`(a pointer) will always be at offset 0 of the structure; the FIRST element of`several`will always be at offset 4 of the structure (offset 0 + {sizeof a pointer}); and`num`will always be at offset 44 of the structure (offset 4 + 10 * {sizeof an int}). The offset may vary some from platform-to-platform and compiler-to-compiler, depending on datatype sizes, memory alignment and such, but will ALWAYS be the same for a given platform-compiler combination.  For the example I've given above, each item of type`struct yo`will be exactly 48 bytes long, with, for example,`num`always being at offset 44 within the struct.